# How to install a stainless steel chimney safely with a metal tube and a concrete foundation?

Tags: concrete, foundation, chimney

I have a stainless steel chimney which I want to connect with the oven inside of my mongolian yurt.
Going through the wall is easy, the hard part is to deploy it safely on the ground so the chimney will not fall over.

The idea is to create a concrete foundation to mount a metal construction tube like this.

[image]

The tube needs to be around 3 meters high. Then I would connect the chimney with something like this.

[image]

Here is the question:

How can I calculate the size diameter/dimension of the tube to ensure it can carry  the weight of the stainless steel chimney. The weight of the chimney is about 40 kg and I would like to connect it at 1.50m and 3m. The full length of the chimney is 4 meters.

What length of the tube needs to be inside the concrete foundation to be stable enough and to avoid a tilt?

In my geo position concrete foundation needs to be around 80cm deep to avoid frost heave.
But how large should it be to not fall over. I guess a block of 50cm x 50 cm x 80 cm should be enough.

Out of the blue I just can guess that having 80cm length of the tube inside the concrete foundation should be enough. Also I can guess a heavy construction tube with 5mm wall and diameter of 5cm should be stable enough.

A lot of guesses but how can I calculate what it really needs?